# How to convert a char or string to hex?

Tags: .net, c++-cli

I want to convert a string to hexadecimal in VC++. Is there any built in function in vc++ to do this. I am working on Visual Studio 2008. Just like VB has some built-in functions, otherwise if there are no built-in functions, any code which anyone can share is appreciated.

Comment: It is not clear what exactly you are trying to achieve. Does your string contain a decimal number which you want to display as a hexadecimal number? Or do you want to display the string character codes as hexadecimal numbers? Or ...

Comment: No i have a string i.e it may be alphanumeric or special symbols or string of any language like chinese, japanese etc etc. even char by char conversion will do the job. i will write a for each loop with my string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit:**

The string formatting functions in the .NET framework allow to specify hexadecimal number output with `:X`:

```
      System::String^ input = "I am a string!";
      System::Text::StringBuilder output;
      for each (System::Byte b in input)
      {
          output.AppendFormat("{0:X} ", b);
      }
      System::String^ hexString = output.ToString();
      Console::WriteLine(hexString);
```

Output:

```
49 20 61 6D 20 61 20 73 74 72 69 6E 67 21
```

**Note**: This will show the raw binary bytes as hexadecimal numbers. If you want to display the Unicode codepoints, you will have to deal with the [`System::Globalization::StringInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.globalization.stringinfo.aspx) class.

Comment: @karthik: I always thought Visual C++ was actually C++. At least the recent versions... (What is the problem with this code? Visual C++ should compile it. Or do you want a .NET Framework based answer?)

Comment: @karthik: I retagged your question and edited my answer to reflect this.

Comment: @Stephan - some of the best answering I've seen! Great answers for both the c++ original solution you provided for the original question and the .net solution you provided for the actual problem.

Comment: `System::Text::StringBuilder output();` declares a nullary function named `output` that returns a `StringBuilder`; you meant `System::Text::StringBuilder output;`.

Comment: You should use {0:X2} to get leading zeros so that it will work for 0-F too ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
int i = 3735928559;
System::String^ str = System::String::Format("{0:X}", i);
```

See documentation for `string.Format` for more details.

Answer (score 0):

wtoi and ltow

will work. The first convert the string to an int, and the second will convert that int to a hex string.

These work for wide strings (2 bytes per char), there are atoi and ltoa versions that work with single byte character strings.

see:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6y51bcy2(v=VS.90).aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yd5xkb5c(v=VS.90).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Well assuming this is a string of single byte characters, each one will be represented by two hexadecimal characters (since a hex digit is represented by 4 bits), so get the lower order bits and the high order bits

```
low = byte & 0xF;
high = (byte & 0xF0) >> 4;
```

which will give you two numbers between 0 and 15, then figure out which digit 0-F it represents.

Comment: If the characters are of more than one byte what shall i do?